# Vue template string compile programmatically to html string

Tags: vue.js

I am getting an HTML email as a string through my API. This email contains Vue template syntax so that the email template can be filled dynamically.

Now I'm trying to parse this string somehow with Vue so that I can populate {{ vars }} there. However, I can't get Vue to return me a string so I can send the finished email HTML.

PS:
`vue-server-renderer` is not possible, because the applications runs on clientSide.

example

```js
const title = 'awesome title'
const `<div> complete e-Mail String with {{ tilte }} </div>`

// parse to and return
// <div> complete e-Mail String with awesome title </div>
```

Is something like this even possible with Vue? Or should I rather use mustache.js for the email syntax?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you can use v-html, do u try ?

Comment: no so the html is rendered into my application. However, I need the html as a string so that I can then send it via axios etc.. or is it possible to use v-html within a method?